# dparse - Python Dependency file parsing

Tags: python, dependency-management

I have a requirement to convert all of the python dependency files eg. requirements.txt and Pipfile, Pipfile.lock to a easily parsable json format.

I chose to use https://github.com/pyupio/dparse. Since its the only repository I could find that does this.

However, I get this error.

```
    print(df.json())
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\dparse\dependencies.py", line 183, in json
    return json.dumps(self.serialize(), indent=2)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py", line 430, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py", line 404, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py", line 325, in _iterencode_list
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py", line 404, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py", line 437, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'SpecifierSet' is not JSON serializable
```

I am only trying to run the example given by the author himself. I installed dparse using 'pip install dparse'

Is there a way around this?

Comment: This issue seems to be specific to dparse library, create an issue in library github issues. [https://github.com/pyupio/dparse/issues](https://github.com/pyupio/dparse/issues)